# Call Telephone Number within a html-viewer IOS iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I need to access an Iphone Function within a html-view. We created an APP that just shows an html-Mobile-Page via an html-view with a native QR-Code Reader and Push Service.

My Problem is that some functions don't work from within an html-viewer: I can't call a phone number

I tried:

`<a href="callto:00491111111111111">Tel: 0111/1111111111</a>`

and:

`<a href="tel:00491111111111111" target="_blank">Tel: 0111/1111111111</a>`

On Safari it works fine but not on the html-viewer of IOS.

With: 
`<a href="#" onclick="prompt('Are you feeling lucky')">Click me</a>`

It opens a prompt - but that is no solution. I need to be able to call the number!

I can't download jpgs.
When I click long on an image the iphone in safari opens a "save image"-prompt. But that doesn't work either on the html-Viewer.

How can I get it fixed? Is there any javascript solution or do I need to modify the html-viewer?

thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: Do you mean you're using `UIWebView`? And using a `tel:` URI doesn't work in your `UIWebView`?

Comment: And your "save image" feature should be asked as a separate question. Keep it to one question at a time, please. Remember that `UIWebView` is _not_ Safari, not even close. A lot of features of Safari must be written yourself if you want to use them with a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply! Yes I mean UIWebView. Is there a way to access the phone function with a javascript snippet? Any Idea how to solve this? p.s. this is my first thread. Ok - I will ask the image problem in a 2nd posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="tel:123456789">Tel: 123456789</a>
```

I lifted this from my working project.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `tel:` hyperlink, just like in Safari:

```
<a href="tel:+004912345">Call me!</a>
```

AFAIK `UIWebView` should already handle the URI correctly (of course, only on the iPhone; it cannot work on iPad or Simulator!). I can't test it right now (Simulator won't do), though.

But what you can always do is handle the URL yourself. Have your view controller implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, set it as delegate to your web view and implement:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        // Let an application that can handle "tel:" URIs open
        // the URL (that is: the "phone" app).
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        // We've handled the URL loading ourself.
        return NO;
    }

    // UIWebView should handle it.
    return YES;
}
```

Again: this will only work on a real iPhone. It will not work on an iPad or Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
window.location.href = 'tel:+18774506120';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an HTML view wrap in a real app? Like with Cordova or some tools like that? If so you need to add this in your config file

```
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
```